# Setting Bool in Element Tree in Python

Tags: python, xml, rest, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to  create a REST request paramter in which i am passing a bool using Element Tree in Python.Can anyone suggest how can i pass a bool in Element Tree.The below throws an error

```
root = ET.Element('dummy_create')
    ET.SubElement(root, 'name').text = name
    ET.SubElement(root, 'isEvaluate').text = True
    return ET.tostring(root)
```

I want isEvaluate to be a bool.Can someone suggest how to do it.i am getting below error now:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 777, in _raise_serialization_error
"cannot serialize %r (type %s)" % (text, type(text).__name__)TypeError: cannot serialize True (type bool)
```

Thanks

Comment: A lot could be suggested but you'd better have agreement with yourself on how to represent boolean values inside your XML (it could be 1/0 or yes/no or just <any string>/<empty string>). After that you either encode/decode that tag in your program or extend ET to do it for you on write/parse.

Comment: Thanks  for the reply.Can you please give a sample code as you suggested?it would be helpful to understand it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass it as `string`:

```
name = 'Hello' # dummy name
root = ET.Element('dummy_create')
ET.SubElement(root, 'name').text = name
# try passing in 'true' rather than 'True'
ET.SubElement(root, 'isEvaluate').text = 'true'

ET.tostring(root)
'<dummy_create><name>Hello</name><isEvaluate>true</isEvaluate></dummy_create>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.This xml is passed to a REST service.The isEvaluated is expected as bool.When i am passing as string on server side its failing as the expectation is true or false.Can you please suggest how to pass it as true or false in the ET?

Comment: @user3062513, can you try passing `1`?

Comment: @user3062513, I have updated my answer, try passing `true` instead, as in XML schema specification, boolean is either `true` or `false`, not `True` or `False` like in Python

Answer (score 1):

To sketch one of the variants:

```
def encode_bool(value):
    if value:
        return 'yes'
    return ''
```

and then

```
ET.SubElement(root, 'isEvaluate').text = encode_bool(True)
```

This way tag will look like `<isevaluate>yes</isevaluate>` or `<isevaluate></isevaluate>`. That will give you either string `'yes'` or an empty string `''` after parsing back, and these strings are `True` and `False` in boolean context.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.When I am setting it as string ,on the server side its not getting received as bool.On server side there is a REST service(jersey) which should auto populate the parameter.This xml is passed as a parameter to a method in the REST service.Can you please suggest what could be the possible way to resolve this issue?